# getting JSON values with swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, webrequest

I have a url that I want get some json data from, when I load the URL in a webpage this is what the json looks like, how can I get these values in swift?

```
{
            "name" : "name value"
            "serial_number" : "serial_numbe value"
            "status" : "status value"
            ...
}
```

this is what i've so far but it isn't working. I am getting an `invalid conversion from throwing function of type...` error on my URLSession.shared call

```
 let web = URL(string: "192.168.101.1:8080/api")
 let webRequest = URLRequest(url: web!)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: webRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
 guard let data = data, error == nil else {return}

                do{
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                    let main = json as? [String : Any] ?? []
                    print(["name"])
                }

            })
```

Comment: `print(["name"])` => `print(main["name"])`? What about using Codable?

Comment: Unrelated but first force unwrap to `[String:Any]` and then conditional downcast to the **same** type is nonsense. Apart from the missing `catch` clause the code doesn't compile anyway. And `.allowFragments` is pointless, too if the expected type is a collection type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax errors in there.

```
    guard let web = URL(string: "192.168.101.1:8080/api") else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: web) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil, let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let serializedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
            guard let json = serializedData as? [String : Any] else { return }
            print(json["name"])
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error)
        }
    }.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let web = URL(string: "192.168.101.1:8080/api")
let webRequest = URLRequest(url: web!)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: webRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {return}

    do{
        let main = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String:Any]
        print(main["name"])

        // or
        let dec = JSONDecoder()
        dec.keyDecodingStrategy =.convertFromSnakeCase
        let res = dec.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    }
    catch {

        print(error)
    }

}).resume()
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let name, serialNumber, status: String
}
```